# So i am playing with Javascript basic and adding elements, but i am having a few hiccups

Tags: javascript

Why doth this not create output when clicking the buttons?
I got functions like this to work before the only difference is the Div elements in changing colors of the buttons, but for whatever reason it does not seem to work. I also just tried playing with variables that i kind of understand, but am not sure as i think they may be causing this problem i just do not know how to solve that issue...HELP ME PLEASE

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset ="utf-8">
    <title>I ROCK YOU MIGHT</title>
    <h1>Lets begin something organized</h1>
    <style>
    #Wrapper{
      background-color:purple;
      text-align:center;
      padding:25px;
    }

    #Wrapper2{
      background-color:red;
      text-align:Left;
      padding:25px;
     }
   </style>
   </head>
   <body>
   <p id="demo">1</p>

    <script>
    var domobject = document.getElementByID("Wrapper");
    var domobejct2 = document.getElelmentById("Wrapper2");
    </script>

    <button onclick="function1">CLICK ME
    <div id= "Wrapper">ELEMENT </div>
    </button>

    <script>
    function function1() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Math.random();
    }
    </script>

    <p id="demo2">3</p>

    <button onclick="function2">CLICKER ME
    <div id="Wrapper2">ELMERHOOD </div>
    </button>
    <script>
    function function2() {
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = Math.random();
    }
    </script>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `onclick="function1"` should be `onclick="function1()"`

Answer (score 1):

In order to invoke a function in the click event you have to call it function1();

```
<button onclick="function1();">CLICK ME
    <div id= "Wrapper">ELEMENT </div>
</button>
```

Comment: nvm i found some typos after in depth examination